# Lua: Skip variable declaration

Tags: lua

I am trying to "Skip" a variable, by either never declaring it or just having it garbage collected immediately, but I don't know if it's possible.

Example:

```
function TestFunc()
   return 1, 2
end

function SecondFunction()
   local nodeclare, var = TestFunc()
end
```

Basically what I wanted was for "nodeclare" to not even exist. So if I did print(nodeclare, var) it would do nil, 2.
The same thing would be if I was doing a pairs loop and I didn't need to use the keyvalue.
Is there some special thing I can put as the variable name for this to happen? If say I was doing a pairs loop over 100 values, would that even have a signifigant impact?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, variables are not garbage collected, *objects* are. In this case, there's nothing to garbage collect.

However, let's say that `TestFunc` *was* creating objects (say, tables):

```
function TestFunc()
   return {1}, {2}
end

function SecondFunction()
   local nodeclare, var = TestFunc()
end
```

Now `nodeclare` is referencing a table returned by `TestFunc`. That's an object, allocated on the heap, that we don't want hanging around forever.

That object will eventually be collected *if* there is nothing left referring to it. In your case, as soon as `SecondFunction` returns, the local `nodeclare` goes out of scope and goes away. As long as there's nothing *else* referencing that table, the table will be collected (during next collection cycle).

You can avoid declaring `nodeclare` entirely by skipping the first return value of `TestFunc` like this:

```
local var = select(2, TestFunc())
```

However, when you're talking about a temporary local variable, as in your example, you normally just create the temporary variable then ignore it. This avoids the overhead of the call to `select`. Sometimes you use a variable name that indicates it's trash:

```
local _, var = TestFunc()
```

---

> If say I was doing a pairs loop over 100 values, would that even have a signifigant impact?

None whatsoever. You're just continually overwriting the value of a local variable.

Comment: Upvoted, but there is a gotcha here. If you call this in a loop, declare the locals outside the loop. Otherwise, instead of overwriting the local, you are shadowing it and this gives more work to the GC.

Comment: @catwell I've not heard of that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @catwell No it doesn't. Lua uses a register-based VM; even if the inner variables shadow the outer ones, each variable is assigned a single register, and this assignment cannot be changed. As Mud said, _variables_ are not GC'd.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo You are right actually, the same register will be re-used so it makes no difference. Although technically it is not the same variable, but it matters only if you create closures. I made a gist to show it here: https://gist.github.com/catwell/9281887

Answer (score 1):

What impact do you mean exactly? Memory? Performance?

According to the [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html) book, you can sort of skip the second return value, but not ignore the first and use the second:

```
x,y = foo2()        -- x='a', y='b'
x = foo2()          -- x='a', 'b' is discarded
x,y,z = 10,foo2()   -- x=10, y='a', z='b'
```

Comment: I was actually already doing this, but I assume there would at some point be an impact when the variable gets gc'd as it goes out of scope. I basically have to loop through a table of up to 200 objects every frame, and I thought maybe saving 200 variable declarations and 200 variables going out of scope (and if they're not declared they can't become un-gc'd upvalues.)

Comment: I don't think you have to worry -- Lua is very well designed and by far the fastest interpreted language.

Comment: Edited my previous comment.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can rewrite the function so that it only returns the value you use? If you mean `pairs()` you don't have to worry as it returns just references to key and value as far as I know.

Comment: I am pretty sure that they actually declare local named variables, because if you set those variables to something, the table remains unaffected, and you can pass them as upvalues when out of scope.

Comment: The variables in Lua are just pointers. I you set them to another value, of course the table remains unaffected.